# Auto Fill the Time in infopath

Tags: time, infopath, autofill

I would like to know if there is a way that I can have the time be auto filled when the user enters 10 I then want it to show 10:00. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the datepicker control.  once you have the control on your form right click on the control and select data picker properties
Select the data type that you want.  Probably dateTime or Text for your scenario.
select the format button next to the data type selection

select `(do not Display Date)` in the top list box and select the appropriate time format in the botton list box.

when you preview the form, when you enter a number like 10, it will be formatted like 10:00 AM assuming that was the formatting selected.